Formulae for polynomial equations of unsolvable degree by extension beyond radicals
There, of course, exists the linear formula and quadratic formula, and then there is the cubic formula of dubious usefulness, and then the quartic formula which is confined to the realm of mere curiosity.
It is well known (Abel-Ruffini) that polynomial equations of degree five or higher do not admit such a general solution in radicals.  However, it is also well known that these equations do have general solutions utilizing other operations (discussed on pretty much anything that talks about them).  The Abel-Ruffini theorem is a marvelous result, but it does not seem to me that it follows from the mere impossibility of an algebraic solution to necessitate kicking a "quintic equation" off the shelves of mathematical curiosities.  My approach to mathematics is to always generalize beyond no-go theorems, and I am certainly not alone in this (examples: the very existence of number systems beyond ℕ, non-Euclidean geometry, self-verifying theories, oracle machines) and yet I cannot find any kind of "quintic equation" written out in the manner of the lower-degree equations, despite the impossibility of an algebraic solution having nothing to do with whether or not you can write out an equation at all!  In fact, there actually exists a general solution (not algebraic.  obviously) to a polynomial of arbitrary degree, but the machinery involved is far too complex for me to understand (and it is poorly documented anyhow).  This proves beyond a shadow of a doubt, I think, that one should be able to showcase equations of much higher degree than four, and yet I have never seen them.  Therefore I humbly request to be shown the forbidden equations with their Bring ultraradicals or (hyper)elliptic functions or theta functions or Fériet functions, or in the absence of these, to be explained why I cannot be shown them (perhaps they are simply too complex).
